# While loop with increment in variable after condition in True

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

Write a loop using while that will increment the money (+1 each time) in a variable
named as pocket,
The loop should be continuous and it would never stop.

Conditions:

- While incrementing when the variable value is less than 300, it will
  print "Earn More money, you are less than 300"
- And if the money is greater than 300. it will automatically empty
  your variable and print "Balance in all your accounts has been
  hacked, you are on zero now"
- This program will continue and will never stops.

Comment: This looks like a homework question or online challenge; please show what you have tried so far and what specifically you are  stuck on. See [ask] and [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions]. We don't mind helping with homework, but we won't do the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the pieces, and let you put them together.

> a variable named as pocket

I'll assume this should start at 0:

```
pocket = 0
```

---

> The loop should be continuous and it would never stop.

```
while True:
    # do stuff
```

---

> While incrementing when the variable value is less than 300, it will print "Earn More money, you are less than 300"

```
print("Get a job!")
pocket += 1
```

---

> And if the money is greater than 300

The question is a bit ambiguous here, since it says "while less than 300 do this, if more than 300 do that"; I'm interpreting that as getting hacked exactly on 300.

```
if pocket == 300: # note the double == for comparison
    # get hacked here
```

You might want to use `if`/`else`, to get hacked in the `if` and do the normal increment in the `else`.